# how to echo the ajax data with the help of php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, echo

I trying to print the data which was entered by the user, and transfer that through ajax and trying to print or echo it with the help of php code, but I could not do that. `enter code here`
this is my code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>
      test ajax
    </title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>test button</h2><br>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="a"><br>
      <input type="button" id="b" value="display">
    </form>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#b').click(function() {
          let a = $('#a').val();
          alert(a);
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "same_file.php",
            data: {
              c: a
            },
            success: function() {}

          });

        });
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
<?php
    extract($_POST);
    if(isset($_POST["c"])) {
    echo $_POST["c"];
    }
 ?>
```

I think that, I have the problem with the php code. please give me any solution.

Comment: Is the ajax call successful?

Comment: Is that code you posted `same_file.php`? You can use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see any requests being made and responses to those. You'd get the complete HTML (with `c` being added at the end). Place the PHP at the top of the file and exit the script after echo'ing `c`

Comment: Please format your code with some sensible indention. It's _very_ hard to read and follow code without any indention at all. Is that how you actually write the code as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

This is your Html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      test ajax
    </title>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>test button</h2><br>
    <form>
      <input type = "text" id = "a" > <br>
      <input type = "button" id = "b"  value = "display" >
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#b').click(function() {
            let a = $('#a').val();
            //alert(a);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "same_file.php",
                data: {c: a},
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                }

            });    

        });
    });
</script>
```

This is your same_file.php

```
<?php
//extract($_POST); code works even without this

if(isset($_POST["c"])) {
  echo $_POST['c'];
}
?>
```

Not sure if your jquery library call is ok so I called the one on the web instead. Also your success:function() was not doing anything which is why you didn't receive anything.

Also always format your code with some indention so that it can be easier to read and comprehend by others.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to echo before the body is rendered.
But in true, unless you need to process the data the user sends, you don't need PHP at all.

And in truth, you probably don't need jQuery as well, fetch() works just fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b').click(function() {
    let a = $('#a').val();
    alert(a);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "same_file.php",
      data: {
        c: a
      },
      success: function() {}
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["c"]))
    {
      // print/echo user data send from form.
      echo $_POST["c"];

      // stop the script from rendering the html below.
      exit();
    }
 ?>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>test button</h2><br>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="a"><br>
      <input type="button" id="b" value="display">
    </form>
    <!-- add script element with js code here -->
  </body>

  </html>
```